# Why request working on android simulator but not working on google play store app?

Tags: android, react-native, https, request, mobile-application

I have basic user login system datas come from http://www.birdpx.com/mobile/m_login (web site belongs to me) adress. But on similator requset working properly but it comes to app that downloaded google play store. Request not working Here is my login codes? By the way everything works on app store correctly .
When submiting the codes (function) below work

```
_handleSubmit=async (values)=>{


    this.setState({
      loading: true
    })


    const datam = { name: values.username, password: values.password };

    const rest = await fetch('http://www.birdpx.com/mobile/m_login', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json', 'Content-type': 'application/json' },
      body: JSON.stringify(datam)
    });


    const gelenVeri = await rest.text();
    let convertedVeri=JSON.parse(gelenVeri);


    if (convertedVeri.status == 1) {


      await this.setState({
        userToken: 1
      })

      let giris = { token: this.state.userToken,user:convertedVeri.kullanici }
     
      await AsyncStorage.setItem('isLoggedIn', JSON.stringify(giris));
      const atama = await AsyncStorage.getItem('isLoggedIn');
      const atamaVerisi = JSON.parse(atama);

     

      if (atamaVerisi.token === 1) {
        
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.props.navigation.navigate('Home');
        }, 2000)


      } else {

        this.setState({
          loading: false
        });
        alert("Beklenmedik Bir Hata Oluştu");
      }
    } else {
      this.setState({
        loading: false
      });
      alert("Giriş Başarısız");

    }

  
  }
```

What do you think about that is that a problem about http/https issue and if it is how can , solve it?

Answer (score 0):

From Android 9 Pie now, requests without encryption(https) will never work. To enable requests to all types of connections HTTP and HTTPS in Android 9 Pie and above, use this attribute to your AndroidManifest.xml where you allow all http for all requests:

```
<application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
</application>
```

Source: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/android-9.0-changes-28#tls-enabled